# Mysql Indexing for Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an ever growing table in MySQL Database. I need to perform a select operation which looks  like:

```
$discountedBooks=
\App\Entities\Books::select('id','published_date','status','chargeable','author')
->whereRaw('DATE(published_date) = "'.$date.'"')
->whereStatus('Completed')
->whereChargeable(1);
```

I have assigned an index to books table

But when I explain the executed query, I don't see the index is being used.
Any suggestions for how should i implement it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which index should be used? There is no index given for the field `published_date`

Comment: Create index on `published_date` instead of `schedule_date`.

Comment: The index image was wrongly uploaded earlier. Updated with the actual image.

Comment: Is `published_date` a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: @Jonas , It is only a date column

Comment: Why are you using `DATE(published_date)`?

Comment: Because i am using whereRaw. Although i can directly use wherePublishedDate($date) ,but the raw query seems fine too, records are fetched properly. Only the index doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Only use `whereRaw()` if you have to (and then use bindings). Just use`wherePublishedDate($date)` or `where('published_date', $date)` and MySQL will use the index.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, It worked. Thank you, If I don't use the raw query, then the index was used by DB. Do you have any explanation, why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `where('published_date', $date)` or `wherePublishedDate($date)`.

MySQL can only use an index if you query the whole column or a left prefix. While `DATE(published_date)` technically returns the whole column, MySQL doesn't know that and therefore can't use the index.

You should only use `whereRaw()` if you have to. If you use it, always use bindings ([SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)):

```
->whereRaw('DATE(published_date) = ?', [$date])
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I will surely take care of it.

Comment: I am sorry, i was unaware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have indexed *scheduled_date*, you are not using it. You are using *published_date* which you should have indexed

Comment: The index image was wrongly uploaded earlier. Updated with the actual image

Answer (score 1):

You have indexed the schedule_date but used published_date. Jus

Comment: The index image was wrongly uploaded earlier. Updated with the actual image